# I want to search my recycle view using edit text or bottom navigation view instead of search menu Android studio. Help me

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to filter my recycle view using an Edit text instead of using a search Menu to search firebase because I want it to be at bottom of my application in Android Studio. For search menu we use onCreate option menu and on Query text submit. What do we use for an edit text?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher())** to search by editText.

```
 EditText enter_gmail;
 enter_gmail = findViewById(R.id.enter_gmail);

    enter_gmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable newText) {
            // pass "newText" to recyclerview filter
            // same as a onQueryTextChange()
        }
    });
```